# Apollo using http instead of ws for subscriptions

Tags: vue-apollo

```js
export default function() {
  return {
    httpEndpoint: "http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql/",
    wsEndpoint: "ws://localhost:8080/v1/graphql",
    wsLinkOptions: {
      reconnect: true,
    },
    websocketsOnly: true,
  }
}
```

When I try to run a subscription, I get:
`error GraphQL error: subscriptions are not supported over HTTP, use websockets instead`

Why is it even using http?

It does eventually connect to the ws endpoint, and if I edit a page after that it refreshes and does query properly. But if I change something in the table I'm subscribing to, everything hangs and I have to restart the server.

Comment: Seems like something's wrong with my ws endpoint, probably not a vue-apollo issue...

Comment: Nope, I got the endpoint working (was the forward slash at the end apparently, lol) but it still has the same error. I can see the ws endpoint connected in the network tab